# How to Search or Match Text from online .txt file?

Tags: c#, .net, text, path, match

I have tried this but it's giving me an error:

> *"The given path's format is not supported".*

```
private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string email = textVarify.Text;
    string line="";
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9013501/bots/lic.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(textVarify.Text))
        {
            DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Email",textVarify.Text+" Found");
        }
        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

What's Wrong with this?

Comment: AFAIK `StreamReader` expects a local file. You can use an `WebClient` to download the file and then stream it. Example: http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_download_text_file

Comment: Happy to help. I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to the [StreamReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) is meant to be a file path in the local system, or to a file share identified by UNC path (e.g. `\\foo\bar\file.txt`); you've provided an HTTPS URL, which is neither.

To retrieve a file via HTTP into a Stream, you'll want something like [WebClient.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/781fwaz8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var uriString = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9013501/bots/lic.txt";

var stream = webClient.OpenRead(uriString);

var file = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan J it solve my problem,that was my first question post and u are awesome to me. thanks one agin..

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer (click the checkmark to the left of it) if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the comments, `StreamReader` expects a local file path. You can use `WebClient` to download the file first.
Here as an example:
[How to download a text file](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_download_text_file)